# data-content not working when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a javascript and jquery for which I need your help:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $( '.website' ).popover(
    {
        'trigger'   : 'click',
        'placement' : 'right'
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-content="www.google.com" class="website" >
    Google Website
</a>
```

When I click on the "Google Website", it displays "www.google.com". But what I want is, when I click on "www.google.com", this URL show open in a new tab also.

What if there is 2 different website like "google.com"; and "yahoo.com"; in the same data-content, so that when clicked on anyone, it should redirect to respective page

How do I do it?

Comment: Popover is completely different thing:-
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers
You can't open a link in a new tab using popover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made some changes in the code, to keep more than on one link in a data-content, you can try it:-

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-content="http://www.google.com" class="website" >
        Google Website
</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-content='http://www.google.com,http://www.yahoo.com' class="website" >
        Websites
</a>
```

And change your javascript like this:-

```
    $('.website').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var dataContents = $(e.target).attr('data-content').split(",");
        for(var i=0; i<dataContents.length;i++){
            window.open(dataContents[i], '_blank');
         }

     })
```

And if popup is blocked in your browser, you've to unblock that. 
I'm trying to open the second window also in a tab rather than in a new window.

Comment: I think in case of opening link in new tab, it's dependent on browser whether the second link will be open in new window or in new tab. In my firefox, both the links are opening in new tabs, but in chrome the second link is being opened in new window. I'm checking if I can fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
$('.website').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 window.open($(e.target).attr('data-content'), '_blank')
})
```

Also make some change in the html:-

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-content="http://www.google.com" class="website" >
Google Website
 </a>
```

You can also add another data-content in the html, and then also it'll work fine.

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-content="www.yahoo.com" class="website" >
Yahoo Website
 </a>
```

Comment: I am facing a problem here. When I click "www.google.com", it opens in a new tab but that URL joins with the existing URL of the page where I clicked.

Comment: sorry for questioning again...what if there is 2 different website like "http://www.google.com" and "http://www.yahoo.com" in the same data-content, so that when clicked on anyone, it should redirect to respective page

Comment: You can add more than one data-content, it'll not give you any issue,

Just add another data-content in your html and test.

Comment: isnt that possbile through same data-content? data-content="http://www.google.com","http://www.yahoo.com"

Comment: First thing is that, you;re specifying a string within data content, so you can't keep two string within one data-content. But we can try it by representing it with an array. But data-content is something that is not visible to the user, User will see the text ("Google Website") and click on that. So do you want, that user will click on the link and both the websites will be opened in two different tabs?

Comment: yes. User clicking on the link and both the websites opening in two different tabs is fine for me

Comment: How to do that, please help. Please

Comment: I've added another answer, you can try it.

Comment: @ user2201935:- Hey, have you tested my new code that I've added. How it's behaving in your side. For me it's working perfectly in Firefox. When I'm clicking on "Google Website" only google's page is being opened new tab, and when clicking on "Websites" both google & yahoo websites are being opened in two new tab. But in google chrome the 2nd website is being opened in a new window. Please let me know waht's happening in your side. I think it's dependent on browser's version.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your `data-content` attribute to include `http://`, otherwise it will open relative to the current url:

```
<a href data-content="http://www.google.com" class="website">
    Google Website
</a>
```

and keep user Indra's code:

```
$('.website').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 window.open($(e.target).attr('data-content'), '_blank');
});
```

JSFiddle Example

**http://jsfiddle.net/BM7Tc/**